# How best to use ConstraintLayout when you want alignment but are unsure of the child widget sizes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create this layout:

[image: ConstraintLayout with two TextView and two EditText children]

My criteria are:

- I want the labels right-justified relative to each other, but otherwise flush left (with margin) within the parent.
- I want the EditText items to fill the remaining space
- Text aligned at the baseline

Knowing that the EditText widgets are taller than the TextView widgets, and that "Password" is wider than "Login", I was able to come up with this layout:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:autofillHints="login"
            android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/login"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
            android:autofillHints="password" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:text="@string/password"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I realize that this depends on invalid assumptions. What would be the "right" way to achieve this layout?

(I realize that this would have been near-trivial using a GridLayout, but I'm trying to learn to use ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following layout. I created a barrier toward the end of the two *TextViews* and constrained their ends to the barrier. The starts are constrained to the parent start. The biases are set to `1.0` to move both to the right. This should give you the right-justified text. (You may need a later version of *ConstraintLayout* for this to work; I used version 2.1.3)

The layout for the *EditTexts* is straightforward.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="loginLabel,passwordLabel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:autofillHints="login"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

There may be an easier way to do all this, but it is not occurring to me at this time.

Comment: Thank you; I will give it a shot and see how it works

Comment: Yep; it worked a treat. I didn't know about Barrier widgets; that made the difference